# Can't connect to my office 2007 mdb database now that i have 64bit computer

Tags: .net, ms-office, oledb

I have an application in vb.net in visual studio 2008.

In my old computer, vista 32 bit system with Microsoft Office 2007 i was able to connect to the access database (mdb file)

Now i bought a new computer which has windows 7 64bit.

I installed my Microsoft Office 2007 (The same i had in previous computer) and Visual Studio 2008.

Problem is now that i cannot connect to the mdb from my application and i get a 
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

I installed Access Database Engine for Microsoft Office 2007 but it didnt fixed it.
When i tried to install Access Database Enginge for Microsoft Office 2010, the x64 version it said it cannot install because i have a 32bit Office in my system.

I know, the first suggestion is to uninstall Microsoft Office 2007 and install the 2010, but is there any other option? I dont wish to use 2010, only if is absolute neccesary.

Important note:
If i compile my application and then run it in my old computer (or other 32 bit systems) it runs perfectly so its not a coding problem. Just a library 32/64 bit problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding a download for the x64 version of just the ACE provider is indeed impossible afaict.  This seems intentional.  Select your EXE project in the Solution Explorer window.  Project + Properties, Compile tab, scroll down, Advanced Compile Options.  Change Target CPU to "x86".

You always want that setting when you debug code, it enables Edit + Continue on a 64-bit machine and avoids a few 64-bit specific hairs.  And keep that setting for the Release build when you have a dependency on any 32-bit unmanaged code, like you do in this case.

Comment: Hello Hans, yes that is the workaround, but let me share a "funny" story on my problem which i eventually solved. I had tried your solution before by reading on other sites, no luck. I posted also here hoping someone will help me.In my case,the problem (after i compiled for x86)was that i have only one hard disk, which of course has the windows 7.So, running my app in visual studio i didnt had "administrator rights" so i can access the mdb file which was on that hard disk. Moving the mdb to my usb stick solved eventually the problem. omg for 5 hours i was re-installing access jet drivers etc..

Comment: Surely the exception you got said something reasonable about this?  Even if it's only an error code.  Be sure to document them well next time you have a similar problem.

Comment: This is what i get "A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll". but when i change from my code the path example: from c:\test\database.mdb to e:\test\database.mdb (same file, remember c is operating system drive, and e is usb stick) it works. maybe am i missing something?

Comment: Review your exception handling.  Make sure you don't catch this exception in your code and produce an error message that hides what the real problem is.  Like `catch(Exception) { MessageBox.Show("Could not open database"); }`

Comment: Hello again Hans, i decided to look my code and see if there were any try/catch that could hide the real problem. While i had the good feeling that my code was finally working, i relaxed and start debugging (yeap relax & debugging can co-exist) and guess what? I found the real problem. As i described i moved to a new computer. Which has 1 drive, my old pc where my app was developed had 2 drives... The path of the MDB file was hard-coded,pointing to D:\folder\database.mdb.... in my new "64bit system" with "32bit Jet driver" there is only the C: and thats where i had put the \folder\database.mdb

Comment: ...so apart of the solution in my orignal question (which is compile for x86 instead of AnyCPU) there is also one valuable lesson.Nothing is granted,even the most obvious things must be checked.That's why there are checklists in airplanes for every procedure,in which the very basic functions also exist and must be checked and double checked. If i had this problem some years ago when i was a beginner programmer possibly i would found that,now that i feel more experienced i skipped the obvious checks and my thought went to the most strange situation! (sorry for bad english)

Comment: also i feel a little embarassed to share my mistakes with you guys. its like a "programmers anonymous" meeting :P

Answer (score 0):

Check : http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/addbuz/thread/13f61a74-3bae-430f-8f3b-66182e5b8f47

Answer (score 0):

try exporting your database to Microsoft Access 2007 format (*.accdb).
Then, change your connection string to:

```
oleDbConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Path + ";";
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Aw it didn't work... Same exception A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll anyway thank you for your help Horse Pen :)